# Package-X has been terminated. FeynCalc and FeynHelpers not working

Tags: physics, feyncalc

I want to compute the finite parts of 1-loop integrals using FeynCalc. One of the most important package used for this is FeynHelpers (which in it uses Package-X).

But, since July 1, 2022, Package-X has to be terminated and I am not able to even download the previous versions. [link](https://packagex.hepforge.org/)

The FeynHelpers mention this in their user manual [link](https://github.com/FeynCalc/feynhelpers-manual/releases/tag/dev-manual): "Package-X is not being developed or even maintained anymore. However, the author of the tool, Hiren H.
Patel, kindly gave us permission to ship OneLoop.m (part of Package-X containing library of analytic results for Passarino-Veltman functions) together with FeynHelpers.
Therefore, no separate installation of Package-X is needed."
But neither I am able to open the file OneLoop.m nor did I find any instruction on how to use it.
When I try to use FeynHelpers anyways, (the function //PaxEvaluate[#,l]&) it gives the following errors,

```
Get::noopen: Cannot open /home/user/.Mathematica/Applications/X/PacletInfo.m.
```

If possible can someone direct me towards downloading older versions of Package-X?

Edit - Sorry! I got the package with its published article [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0010465517301297)

Comment: Did you check the internet archive in case they have an earlier snapshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one also might be interesting

https://gitlab.com/mule-tools/package-x

Answer (score 2):

I think this one will work::::
https://data.mendeley.com/datasets/yfkwrd4d5t/1